# Pegar Resposta de uma API que retorna erro 500

Tags: javascript, json, api, react

Seguinte, tenho uma API que retorna erro 500 toda vez que infringe a regra de negócio me retornando um status e uma mensagem. Sabemos que não é uma boa prática retornar status 500 nessas circunstâncias, mas tem alguma forma de eu pegar o JSON que ela me retorna, mesmo ela estourando status 500?

Ele não cai nem no `then` nem no `cath`

Comment: Coloca o código pro pessoal te ajudar melhor

Answer (score 2):

De forma bem simples, você nunca vai conseguir, entenda o por que.

O motivo é, erros com código de `500` a `599`, são normalmente associados a erros na aplicação de servidor, que falhou ao operar uma requisição.

O que você deve fazer é primeiro, qualquer erro dentro desse intervalo entre `500` e `599`, deve ser tratado como falha na API e você deve trata-lo mesmo sem saber o motivo da falha. Ou seja, verifique o `httpstatus` antes de qualquer coisa, se estiver entre `500` e `599`, trate como uma falha na API e não espere que ela te retorne o motivo da falha.

Tenha em mente que, se você manda um valor que a API não espera e ela retorna um erro `500` por exemplo, é porque provavelmente o tipo do valor que você está mandando é inesperado.

Oposto a situação acima, se a API trata um tipo de dados que não é o esperado, é bem provável que ela retorne para você um erro `400` e o motivo do erro.

**Referência**: [Lista de códigos de status HTTP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_c%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP)

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar a mensagem de erro 500 de uma requisição POST com JavaScript usando o Axios, você pode usar o método axios.post() para enviar a requisição e, em seguida, verificar o status da resposta. Se o status for "500", você pode acessar a mensagem de erro através do objeto error.response.data. Aqui está um exemplo:

```
axios.post('your_url',{data: your_data})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.response.status === 500) {
      console.log(error.response.data);
    }
  });
```